# How to merge multiple datatypes of an union type in avro schema to show one data type in the value field instead of member0 member1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have the following avro schema

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": 
        {
        "type": "map",
        "values": ["int","string"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I am streaming some events via kafka to spark with this schema, the streaming data frame depicts the data field as a struct with members with the datatypes specified in the schema as shown in the below image.

[Schema format of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BKh1.png)

Is there any possibility to merge the members to only show the value of the key rather than splitting and representing it as multiple members

so like `number : -64`

rather than `number : { member0 : -64 , member1 : null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to merge them and that is how avro works for a union datatype. Might have to live with it.

Comment: No other way to do it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).